# Netbeans 12.2 hanging when connecting to XDebug 3

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I have a clean install of Windows 10 and have installed xampp 7.4.15 and XDebug 3.0.2.
php has been configured to use xdebug.
I have been unable get debugging for PHP working. In the following details, I can prove that xdebug is configured and working (using dbgpClient) and that xdebug is connecting to netbeans (using the xdebug log).
What I can't work out is why it is hanging. Any help would be appreciated. I am now well and truly outside my confort zone!

This is added php.ini to set up xdebug

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp_7_4_15\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=true
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.log="C:\xampp_7_4_15\apache\logs\xdebug.log"
```

I have confirmed it works using dbgpClient.exe

```
Connect from [::1]:50298
DBGp/1.0: Xdebug 3.0.2 — For PHP 7.4.14RC1
Debugging file:///C:/Users/david/Documents/LanarWeb/Lanar/public/index.php (ID: 8772/)
(cmd) step_into
1 | step_into > break/ok
1 | file:///C:/Users/david/Documents/LanarWeb/Lanar/public/index.php:12

(cmd) status
2 | status > break/ok

(cmd) step_into
3 | step_into > break/ok
3 | file:///C:/Users/david/Documents/LanarWeb/Lanar/public/index.php:14
```

When I try to run the website from netbeans in debug mode, the browser opens and hangs.
If I stop debugging using Shift-F5, a dialog box is displayed.
[image: Netbeans error message]

If I check in the xdebug.log file, there are these transactions. Note the last one is a feature_set. There are no more entries in the log file, even after the debugging session is closed.

```
[2584] Log opened at 2554-07-21 23:34:32.995542
[2584] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[2584] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[2584] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/Users/david/Documents/LanarWeb/Lanar/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.14RC1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2584"><engine version="3.0.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[2584] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 0 -n show_hidden -v 1
[2584] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="0" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[2584] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n max_depth -v 3
[2584] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[2584] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 30
[2584] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[2584] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_data -v 2048
[2584] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>
```

That is all that is in the log. There is no more messages and no 'Log Closed'. It seems xdebug has stopped.
Any tips appreciated.